# Does Microsoft Speech Platform 11 supports Win8 and tablets?

Tags: windows-8, speech-recognition, tablet, microsoft-speech-platform

Does Microsoft Speech Platform 11 supports Win8  and tablets?
About tablets- does it supports Win-tablets?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Microsoft Speech Platform 11 supports Windows 8  and tablets ,

More Detail To Visit This Link

http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=27224

Comment: Do read the System Requirements section in the link you posted.  It lists the supported operating systems, neither tablets nor Windows 8 are listed.

Comment: But you can use it in your windows 8 is Provide to compatibility of windows 7 That's why  Microsoft Speech Platform 11 supported